# Named anchors in customized elements of Dart polymer dose not work?

Tags: html, dart, anchor, dart-polymer

Inside the customized elements of Dart polymer, the named anchors dose not seem to work:

```
<h1 id="top">My web page</h1>
<div>
</div>
<a href="#top">Top of page</a>
```

Any ideas about the reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but maybe you should declare it as LightDOM to make work. I had a similar problem a little ago and this helped . Check about it [here](http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.html#attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your element's [Shadow DOM](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html) is not exposed, not accessible from the outside. The "normal" DOM does not hold information about those elements, and querying the DOM yields no results.

If you use `document` (as in `document.querySelector('#top')`) to query your element, you might want to create a reference to your Shadow Dom, and use `shadowRoot` instead of `document`.

Sorry for my clumsy explanaton. But [Polymer's Shadow DOM page](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html) should help you solve your problem.